# Can firebug detect ajax operations that are in progress?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, scripting, firebug

The firebug console has various panels that can keep track of a lot of information. The net panel keeps track of almost all network traffic and reports various pieces of information on that traffic, e.g. headers, latency, request parameters, etc. What I would like to do is access all this information programatically from the javascript panel because I have a script that needs to know if there is a request in progress. I haven't found any documentation on how the various panels interoperate or if they are even aware of each other. I need to make the script as generic as possible so tying the script to the code on the page is not desirable because the script would not operate on other pages because of minor quirks like function names not being the same.

Comment: How does this script "run in Firebug"? What does that mean?  Where does the script come from?

Comment: @Pointy he is injecting it directly to the console

Comment: @Eric Fortis - well I guess so but it's not clear how that fits in with a "social experiment".  So that means it's basically like a bookmarklet?  My real question I guess is what this "Firebug" execution context is, and how it's different from what code in a bookmarklet has available to it (or code in the page, for that matter).

Comment: @Pointy: The firebug execution context is the same as the execution context of any other javascript on the page, at least that's how I understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is to gain access to Firebug's internal functionality, which can only be done if they expose an API. As far as I know, they don't expose an API to **javascript**, other than the familiar `console` object.

What they do have however, is an API for firefox plugin development. So you can create a firefox plugin that then either extends the Net panel of firebug to do what you want, or exposes another javascript object called `console.net` or something like that.

Here is a good tutorial (well, part of a tutorial series) that explains specifically how to listen to events in the net panel: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug-tutorial/extending-firebug-net-panel-listener-part-viii/

Answer (score 1):

Check out firebug plugin [NetExport](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/netexport/)

Edit: [Here is the source code:](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/#svn/netexport/branches/netexport0.7)

Also this source code may interest you [tracingconsole](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/#svn/extensions/tracingconsole/branches/tracingconsole0.5)

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I know, the only way to really "know" about in-flight XMLHttpRequests is to explicitly "remember" them in the code. It's like timeouts and interval timers - if your code doesn't hang on to a handle, it's lost.

If the pages in question do everything via jQuery or some other framework, then it might be possible to worm into that code and leverage whatever's done to track ajax work, but exactly how you'd do that would depend on the framework.

It might help your progress if you were to explain more about what it is you want to achieve with this technique. In other words, while what you asked about directly may not be possible, it might be possible to find another way to do whatever it is you want.

Comment: I've modified my question to add more information and what I'm specifically trying to do. Basically I need to access the net panel from the javascript panel.

Comment: Well the problem is that from "regular" code executing in the context of the *page*, all that extra stuff is not visible. From the XUL side of the fence, it's there of course. It might be possible to fool with Firebug itself to see if there's a way to code up some APIs for the network activity panel (etc).